# Why can't I change an equation before I differentiate it?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

So recently I was reviewing calculus, and I tried to differentiate the equation: $(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)=1/2$

The first thing I did was make the equation easier to differentiate by multiplying the whole equation by $(x^2+y^2)$ to get $x^2-y^2=(1/2)x^2+(1/2)y^2$
Then I differentiated: $d/dx (x^2-y^2)=d/dx((1/2)x^2+(1/2)y^2)$
This should differentiate to: $2x-2yy'=x+yy'$ Then I simplified it to: $x=3yy'$ and then to $y'=x/3y$

However, Wolfram alpha tells me the answer is  $y'=y/x$. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 4):

No mistake.  From your equation, $x^2=3y^2$.  So $x/3y$ is the same as $y/x$.

Comment: I tend to have more 'unique' proofs when differentiating. Will teachers be able to tell this answer is correct, and will they care if its different?

Comment: If they can't tell and do care, then you have to explain to them why your answer is correct!